# SSD or memory, which should I replace to resolve a freeze problem?

Tags: memory, ssd, memory-card

I've replaced a motherboard and a CPU but still I've been suffered by a high frequency freeze problem.

Especially a freeze occurs as I use vscode. In sometime, just opened the vscode caused a freeze.

So the memory and the SSD are two of the remnants components which is (are) cause (s) a freeze.

Due to the economic problem, I can only replace memory or SSD.

Which should I replace (or attach a memory)?

The below components are mine:

- [CPU(i5 10th generation)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/Generation-Corei5-10400F-BX8070110400F-Japanese-Distribution/dp/B086MHSTWN) with default cooler
- [Memory(4_GB)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WVSLBHG)
- [motherboard](https://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=1008)
- [graphic card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AZ7W88O) ( I newly attached it to the computer.)
- [SSD](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Palit-UVS10AT-SSD120-120-GB-Internal/dp/B072MRMF37)

The minimum temperature of the CPU is around 32 celsius

What I got typed:

```
sudo hwinfo --short
```

Results in this:

[image: hwinfo output]

Comment: How many sticks of ram do you have in your PC?

Comment: oh, you have linux...  thats a different program than the one I know...

Comment: @Salocor I think I use only one stick of RAM which has been attached on the motherboard.

Comment: Darn.  I was thinking if you had two you could test them one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mounted [this dual-memory](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Memory/VENGEANCE-LPX/p/CMK8GX4M2A2666C16) to my motherboard and the problem of freezes has not been solved.

So I bet the ssd is the criminal.

Comment: do not overlook the **power supply** being the cause of strange problems. The SSD*isk* if it is the problem should show evidence of SATA I/O errors and timeouts in log files.  But with sata ssd's being $20 these days it's not difficult to get an additional one to have on hand for troubleshooting, certainly cheaper than a quality power supply.

Answer (score 0):

I think none of them. I would recommend spend some on a better CPU cooler. The boxed coolers from Intel are not so good. Try searching for a top-flow cooler like the Be quiet! Shadow Rock TF 2.

Why I would recommend this is that your CPU only runs at low clock speeds with insufficient cooling (or the boxed cooler). If the turbo boosts it to a high frequency, it can overheat, and starting programs with fast storage tends to use the CPU a lot. (Booting visual studio 2019 uses my CPU close to 100% for a short time (Ryzen™ 3 3100).

My CPU can heat up to 80°C and cool down to 18°C (room temperature, only when off).

Comment: My cpu temperature still records around 32_c so I bet the problem is triggered by ssd or memory.

Comment: Yea, if it's cool, maybe indeed memory.... Can you try Corsair (LPX) RAM in dual channel instead of that random cheap stick?

Comment: Ok I may try it.